# Error handling with Drupal.ajax()

Tags: 8, ajax

First I am not very good in JavaScript so maybe I do not know some very basics... I apologize in advance.

I created a form where I want to save every change in single fields directly without the need to submit the form each time. Therefore I created a custom route which returns an AjaxResponse on successfull database savings as well as on any errors on the Drupal side.

But I want to be aware of any errors which may appear on the client side as well. `$.ajax()` has the function `.fail()` and `.done()` where I can do different things in my JavaScript when something went wrong. These methods are missing for `Drupal.ajax()`. Is there any way to react on errors when using `Drupal.ajax()`?

I tried

```
try {
  Drupal.ajax({url: path}).execute();
}
catch (e) {
  alert(e.name + ": " + e.message);
}
```

and built in some errors on my controller but all that happens is that the browsers console lists Ajax errors - no alert is shown to the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can using like jQuery ajax. Because `Drupal.ajax({}).execute()` is a function and return the jqXHR.

```
 /**
   * Execute the ajax request.
   *
   * Allows developers to execute an Ajax request manually without specifying
   * an event to respond to.
   *
   * @return {object}
   *   Returns the jQuery.Deferred object underlying the Ajax request. If
   *   pre-serialization fails, the Deferred will be returned in the rejected
   *   state.
   */
  Drupal.Ajax.prototype.execute = function() {
    // Do not perform another ajax command if one is already in progress.
    if (this.ajaxing) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      this.beforeSerialize(this.element, this.options);
      // Return the jqXHR so that external code can hook into the Deferred API.
      return $.ajax(this.options);
    } catch (e) {
      // Unset the ajax.ajaxing flag here because it won't be unset during
      // the complete response.
      this.ajaxing = false;
      window.alert(
        `An error occurred while attempting to process ${this.options.url}: ${e.message}`,
      );
      // For consistency, return a rejected Deferred (i.e., jqXHR's superclass)
      // so that calling code can take appropriate action.
      return $.Deferred().reject();
    }
  };
```

[source](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.0.x/core/misc/ajax.es6.js#L657)

So in your case:

```
var ajaxExecute = Drupal.ajax({url: path}).execute();

ajaxExecute.done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!